# Submenu click not working with actions

Tags: html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, action

[image]

Not able to click on submenu in our application.  As per the attached picture. I am trying to achieve below scenario steps:

1. Click on `Menu 1`
2. MouseOver on `<Item 3>`
3. Click on `Sub Item 2`

I have tried below code and not able to click on Sub Item 2, Because the issue is when selenium is trying to click on Sub Item 2, the focus/cursor/mouseover changed from Item 3 to Item 1. And 2nd sub item present in Item 1 got clicked.

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Menu 1")).click();
WebElement item3 = driver.findElement(By.linkText("<Item 3>"));
Actions action = new  Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(item3).pause(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).build().perform();
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.linkText("<sub Item2>")))
.click().build().perform();`
```

Please help me with the solution to handle this situation.

Comment: Can you please share HTML code?

Comment: @AnkurSingh - Sorry, cannot share HTML Code. They will fire me out if i share :-P

Answer (score 1):

You can make it as chained actions. It may work for you.

```
WebElement menu1 = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Menu 1"));
WebElement item3 = driver.findElement(By.linkText("<Item 3>"));

Actions action = new  Actions(driver);
action.click(menu1).moveToElement(item3).click(driver.findElement(By.linkText("<sub Item2>"))).build.perform();
```

Comment: I tried the above one and it throws me exception "Unable to find webelement : Subitem2 "

Comment: I have also used new WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(subitem2));

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with link text == subItem2
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.7.1', revision: '8a0099a', time: '2017-11-06T21:07:31.527Z'

Comment: try with any other locators instead of link text for the sub item 2. it may help

Answer (score 0):

As per your steps :

1. Click on Menu 1
2. MouseOver on Item 3
3. Click on Sub Item 2

Here is the pseudo code block :

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Menu 1")).click();
WebElement item3 = driver.findElement(By.linkText("<Item 3>"));
Actions action = new  Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(item3).build().perform();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("<sub Item2>")).click();
```